# Should I use Delegate Classes if I want items to be edited using a dialog in Qt?

Tags: qt, delegates, model-view-controller, qitemdelegate

All examples in Qt show that one should use delegate classes to provide editors that **reside within `QTreeView`** (`QListView`, etc). I want to have a separate non-modal dialog to edit item's attributes. Should I use delegate classes to do so?

That is, no editing or special behavior is required within `QTreeView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly could create your dialog as a delegate, but I don't think I'd go that far.  Just make sure that your separate dialog is updated appropriately when the model's data changes, or the view changes selection. (And tracking the selection changes could be made quite a bit easier, in my opinion.)